# CSS - Using multiple css classes in sentence

Tags: html, css

```css
.dot {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red-tag {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Online sales this quarter were</p>
  <div class="dot" />
  <p class="red-tag">HIGH</p>
  <p>Predictions indicate sales will continue to rise.</p>
</div>
```

I am attempting to write a sentence using different css classes. At the moment I am having issues keeping them all in-line. I am expecting the outcome of the sentence to flow in one sentence just like:

> Online sales this quarter were (css dot) HIGH. Predictions indicate sales will continue to rise.

Currently, after adding a the `.dot` tag; it shows on the line below and due to the inline block it affects the sentence after it. I am attempting to have it all sitting in one line. I've tried accomplishing this by wrapping my sentence in a `div` tag; as well as switching `<span class="dot">` to `<div class="dot"/>` which ended up giving me the same result.

Comment: A few errors: `div` are not self closing, so that's invalid HTML. `p` tags are block level elements so they will always (unless you change properties in CSS) - move to the next line. Change all your `p` and that `div` tags to `span` or use CSS to change the p to `inline` e.g. `p { display: inline }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag to mark up something that isn't a paragraph.
You should use the [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) tag (which is a generic inline contar) instead of `<p>`.

```css
.dot {
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.red-tag {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Online sales this quarter were</span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="red-tag">HIGH</span>
  <span>Predictions indicate sales will continue to rise.</span>
</div>
```